# issuing a parameter via a URL == issuing a parameter via query strings

Tags: kohana

Is issuing a parameter via a URL the same as issuing a parameter via query strings? (in Kohana)

Here is the example:

```
verify.php?uid=5&token=TOKEN
```

Is the above that code the same as below this code?

```
verify/5/TOKEN
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kohana "issuing a parameter via a URL" will show up as a parameter to your controller function.
"Issuing a paramter via query strings" is available via the [input library](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/input)

If the parameter is core to the identity of your resource... keep it in the url.
Example:
www.example.com/our/presidents/Barack_Obama

Your controller code controllers/our.php

```
class Our_Controller {
    public function presidents($full_name)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could transform the 1st to the 2nd one by doing this

```
class Something_Controller {

    public function verify($uid, $token) {
        // whatever

    }


}
```

Otherwise you'd use the input library like so

```
$uid = $this->input->get('uid');
```

Depending on what settings you have in config/config.php, you may be automatically making it safe from XSS attacks.

Comment: is there any siginificant difference between getting it via get and getting it via segments?

Comment: Not really - You just specify it differently. The arguments in the forward slash mapping become arguments to your method - however the GET vars function as expected.